# Changing background of LinearLayout changes it's width & height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I tried to change background of a LinearLayout to some wood texture, but it changes LinearLayout width and height depending on dimensions of the wooden background!
I need LinearLayout to disregard background dimensions!

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/wood"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

some content here which I need to wrap height to them!

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202647/setting-a-background-image-to-a-view-stretches-my-view

Answer (score 4):

Your `LinearLayout's` height is `"wrap_content"`. Which means it takes height of the content(your background). You can change it to `"match_parent"` or give it a fixed size in `dp`. So that it remains same even with background.

Comment: But I want it to size to my real content, not the background.

Comment: Give your parent layout a "weightSum" and its children "weights" according to your layout. Make height's of all children 0dp.

Comment: For more info, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 0):

If You want it to be of fixed either use fixed height and width in dp Or dynamically calculate height and width of old background and then apply new background with setting LinearLayout height and width to be of size you calculated programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced it with another container such as `ConstraintLayout`.. I don't have time to figure it out.